# Representation part in a RMR architecture

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I think I have a problem in the separation of concerns for a php application using RMR architecture.
The goal of this project is to learn, so I don't use any framework, I want to understand things.
So I'm doing a simple CMS using PHP in OOP and the RMR architecture. I should be modular, in order to add module, like search on the site, gallery, etc... (Yes, perhaps it can become a good base for future projects).
It will not be a real backend. An admin tools will be showed when logged in on the page that frontend users can see, and editing will be done through AJAX.

So this is my goal.

At the moment, things are as follows:
Any url is redirected to `example.com/index.php`.
This files create a Application object and run it:

```
<?php
    require_once('Library/Autoload.class.php');
    Library\Autoload::register();
    $app = new Library\Application;
    $app->run();
```

Then I saw things like this:
First, I analyze the request (url) which looks like: `example.com/resourceType/resourceAlias`
Then I will create an instance of `$resourceType` and execute it. The args are `resourceAlias` and next parameters existing in the url.
The return is an array that looks like this for a standard page:
`array('title' => $content->name(), 'content' => $content->content())`
I pass it to the Page which represent what will be showed to the guest.

```
public function run(){
    list($resourceType,$args) = $this->processRequest();
    $resourceData = $this->executeResource($resourceType, $args);
    $this->page->setResource($resourceData);
    $this->page->setUser($this->user);
    $this->page->setTpl($this->config->get('config','tpl'));
    $this->page->setMenu($this->getMenu());
    $this->page->render();
}
```

And the problem is here.

- I don't know if what I give to the page is in the correct format (key->value array).
- The data coming from resource must be formatted into HTML (generally). For example the array representing the hierarchy of the pages can become a html list for a menu. In MVC it is the job of a view, but in RMR, who do this? I thought that RMR-Representation != MVC-View.
- A template will define the final rendering. I thought that the Page `has-a` template, so I give the name of the template (coming from the config file) to the page. But here the Page don't know which variables the template is waiting for. So it is NOT modular... How to do this ?
- Then here the Application `has-a` User, User is not a resource (logically). But if I want, to log a user in, to call `example.com/user/login` with `$_POST['username']`, the resource will not exist. I don't know how to design this thing.

I admit I have not well-understand all the architecture. I tried to analyze this framework: [Rest-RMR](https://github.com/QUTlib/rest-rmr) But that doesn't help me a lot.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what exactly is your question? Also, what is that static disaster to which you linked?

Comment: My questions are below "And the problem is here".
So how would you change my current architecture to become a right RMR and become modular?
I think I have bad designed the basis...